# SpringBoot-OpenAPI: How to add default header to all requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi

I have created an OpenAPI spec as below.

```java
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        final String securitySchemeName = "Authorization";
        final String apiTitle = "My Service";
        return new OpenAPI()
                .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName))
                .components(
                        new Components()
                                .addSecuritySchemes(securitySchemeName,
                                        new SecurityScheme()
                                                .name(securitySchemeName)
                                                .type(SecurityScheme.Type.APIKEY)
                                                .in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER)))
                .info(new Info().title(apiTitle));
    }
```

Now, I want OpenAPI UI to add one extra header `MyCustomHeader:MyValue` to all the requests. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define [OpenApiCustomiser](https://javadoc.io/static/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-common/1.5.10/org/springdoc/core/customizers/OpenApiCustomiser.html) bean as follows:

```java
@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser openApiCustomizer() {
  return openApi ->
      openApi.getPaths().values().stream()
          .flatMap(pathItem -> pathItem.readOperations().stream())
          .forEach(
              operation ->
                  operation.addParametersItem(
                      new HeaderParameter()
                          .schema(new StringSchema()._default("MyValue"))
                          .name("MyCustomHeader")));
}
```

The bean adds the `MyCustomHeader` header to all endpoints with `MyValue`
as default value.